# DataAccessException response status

Tags: database, spring, http, spring-mvc

If code called by a Spring controller throws a Spring `DataAccessException`, and the controller does not catch it or have an exception handler for it, will Spring return an appropriate HTTP response status to the client?

That is, do the `DataAccessException`s have suitable `@ResponseStatus` annotations? Or does the Spring MVC framework explicitly catch those exceptions and handle them? Or does the framework do nothing special for them, treating then like any other `RuntimeException`, which I guess results in an HTTP status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`DispatcherServlet.doService`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java) (and the subsequent methods it delegates to) just delegate an exception to the servlet container if Spring has no handler for it. Spring by default has handlers that use the `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseStatus` annotations, and a promising-looking `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`. But the later does nothing with `DataAccessException`s. So, Spring MVC does nothing special for `DataAccessException`s.

If you want to map `DataAccessException`s to specific HTTP response status codes you can [use an `@ExceptionHandler` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

It looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "foo")
  public void foo() throws DataAccessException {
    ...
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleException(DataAccessException ex) {
    return "error message";
  }
}
```